# Angular - How to get selected cell value from mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

How to get the value from selected cell of a mat table. I attached a sample code in which, the row and index can be fetched. But i want the value from the selected cell.

I attached a sample code at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-row-select-sr1gqu?file=app/table-selection-example.ts) and required format in image
below,

### [required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8nTq.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the value of the selected column you can make the `cell` as HTMLElement and get the text from it. You can add this in the code:

```
select(event: MouseEvent, cell: HTMLElement) {
    
     const value = cell.textContent;
     console.log(cell.textContent);
     
     .....
     .....
```

Comment: Does this help?